# Why is the epsilon-delta method needed?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, intuition, epsilon-delta

I heard that the reason epsilon delta method is used is that the original limit is intuitive.

Then why is intuition wrong? Is there any way of proving that?
Is there any example which is solved not by limits, but only by the epsilon-delta method?

Comment: In mathematics we need rigorous definitions. What do you mean by "solving by limit" if not by using the definition of a limit?

Comment: Typically, the *intuitive notion* of a limit involves applying the function to a number which is infinitely small, but not equal to zero.  Within the mainstream framework of modern mathematics, such a number does not exist.

Comment: I edited your answer to improve the grammar. Hope I didn't change the meaning.

Comment: Here's an example that can't be solved by the usual "rules" of limits:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \in \Bbb Q\\
x & x \notin \Bbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
(where $\Bbb Q$ denotes the rational numbers). We can prove with the epsilon-delta definition that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "why is intuition wrong"? In which case is it wrong?

Comment: I see no reason for downvotes, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: That episilon delta method is the formal definition of the limit. But there are other ways to prove the existence of limit

Comment: Yeah why rude and down votes?

Comment: I downvoted and voted for close because the question seems not to be clear enough. Nobody claims that intuition is wrong, etc etc

Comment: (to Eff) Well, which I said the original limit means x approaches to c but x!=c. I'm sorry about that. (to Omnomnomnom) Thank you so much. the example was helpful to me. (to GoodDeeds) I am not good at English, so I can't explain to understand all of you. Thank you for editing my question. (to Sathasivam K) Thank you for add comment to advice. If I was impolite, I apologize. sorry. (to Peter Franek) thank you for your voting. I'll take effort more. (to everyone that add comment my question)Thank you very much, everyone. I was surprised that many comment was added already. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Intuition fails to get the right answers often (Cantor's theorem and the Weierstrass's function are examples) so mathematics needs to be made rigorous to avoid these, precise definitions like the epsilon-delta definition of a limit need to be used.

I think it is quite intuitive, it states that a function $f$ reaches a limit $L$ at a point $a$ if and only if we can make $f$ as close to $L$ as we want it to be (within epsilon. That's why it's for all epsilon, any can be chosen for the desired precision) if we consider points which are close enough to $a$ (this is the delta part. There is (there exists) some delta which makes sure $f(x)$ is within epsilon of $L$ if $x$ is within delta of $a$, we have to make $x$ close enough to $a$).